# React js : display table row data in page or a pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, reactjs

I have a table filled with users details (user(name,id....)). I want to display the details of an user when I click on a table row and even edit and save the modification.

I already did the table part, can anybody give me ideas?

Comment: did you see inline edit react components ? try https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-edit-inline or https://github.com/kaivi/riek

Comment: thank you very much it was really helpfull.